# Expanded implementation of php interfaces

Tags: php, oop, interface

PHP's manual on [Object Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) says:

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

No consider the following case: I have an interface

```
interface Foo
{
    public function foo(SpecialClass $object);
}
```

which contains just a method `foo` which takes a `SpecialClass` as an argument, and a concrete class

```
class Bar
{
    public function foo(BaseClass $object)
    {
        // do something with $object
    }
}
```

that has the same signature of `Foo` excepts of the fact that `foo` takes  a `BaseClass`, where `SpecialClass implements BaseClass`.

Thinking theoretically, whenever in my code I need something to satify `Foo` interface, I could use an instance of `Bar` and everything should work (beacuse a SpecialClass is a BaseClass). In other words, `Bar` satisfies the contract declared by `Foo` because it has a method `foo` that is able to handle any `SpecialClass` object.

To make this explicit, and be able to actually use it in my code, I'd like to be able to write `Bar implements Foo`, but that, as stated in the documentation, throws a fatal error.

What is the reason for this fatal error? Is it just because things are done like this at the moment or is there a specific reason to do things this way?

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is not a StdClass, they are actually two different class.

This is not Java, where everyone extends from Object

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the question with two generic classes inheriting one from the other

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @dynamic `DataTime` is not `stdClass`. Take a look at the following example.

```
class A {
    public function foo();
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo();
    public function bar();
}

interface C {
   public function baz(B $obj)
}

class D implements C {
    public function baz(A $obj);
}
```

You can see that the `C` interface's function `baz` takes argument `B`. The implementation however takes argument `A`. The problem is that `B` has more extended interface and `A` doesn't satisfy it. In other words `C` interface is requiring access the `foo()` and `bar()`. But `A` has only `foo()`. If it was the opposite however the things would work - `B` satisfies the `A`'s interface.

So this is not a temporary behavior and is correct one.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but actually @dynamic is right. `DateTime` is not `stdClass` you can check that: `var_dump(new \DateTime instanceof \stdClass);` will result to `false`

Comment: I corrected the example with two generic classes extending one from the other. Moreover, I'm not sure I'm following your answer: could you please improve it providing an example showing how what I'd like to do does not work?

Comment: I don't agree and I think you're wrong when you say that `C interface is requiring access the foo() and bar()`, because `C` is just an interface. What will be done with `$obj` is just a responsibility of the implementation, not of the interface itself. From my point of with, `C` is just saying that any its implementation will ba able to manage a `B` object passed to its `baz` method. And `D` is actually able to manage any `B` object passed to its `baz` method

Comment: I'm figuratively speaking what I say 'requiring access'. Your point of view may be also correct but \when you inject an object do you want to manage it or to use its functionality to get some job done? Can you give example, a general one will be better,  where you're passing object to manage it?

Comment: just sketched down something in a concrete case where what I'd like to have could be useful... https://3v4l.org/naSJm feel free to edit it

Comment: I think I see your point. But if you and to treat a subclass as it superclass, if the interface takes as argument the superclass, from my example, you are passing instance of `B` that should be cast to `A` and it will be confusing. I read this somewhere in SO: An interface is a contract. This means i'll give at least `B`. `A` as less than `B`. Again figuratively speaking.

Comment: You're right to say that the interface is a contract. But is a contract to do exactly that or to do that and possibly more? I'd say the second, since that's also the case when you have other methods in an implementing class

Comment: That's what I said: 'at least'

Comment: The problem is where to put the "at least". If you say "bar must be able to treat an object of class at least B", you get your point of view. If you say "bar must at least be able to treat a class B" (i.e. if it receives a B, it will be able to handle it), you get my point of view.